# Are faceplates for xbox one s and xbox one controller interchangeable?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

I have a very nice faceplate for an Xbox One controller, and I have an Xbox One S controller. Is it possible to put the faceplate on my controller? I don't want to void the warranty only to find out it is impossible.

I know the Xbox One S faceplate is only one piece, but is it possible to change those parts to fit anyway?